# How to backup My local Database from release APK?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I need to backup my data from an app installed on my android device. I am using the sqflite data base for storing the data to a local database. I was use flutter to develop the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can start using any backend like Firebase which is a paid backend service from Google with a free tire
After you [create](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios) a project you can start using [FireStore](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/) to back up your SQFLite database files